# Is there a way to exclude blank excel cells on import using oledbadapter in a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, oledb

Hello I'm trying to find a way to trim blank cells on my datagridview if the excel cells are blank on import. I found this on MDSN but it doens't seem to be working. Maybe something along these lines will work. I greatly appreciate any help anyone can give!

```
 Dim Empty As Boolean = True

 For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
Empty = True
For j As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    If dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() <> "" Then
        Empty = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Empty Then
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
End If
```

Next

Answer (score 0):

One problem is you need to work from the bottom up on the DGV:

```
        For i As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0
```

If you work from the top down the index of any given row below the row removed changes.